# How to correctly implement maximum weight independent set of positive tree using BFS

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic, breadth-first-search

Can someone help me implement the maximum weight independent set for a TREE (not a graph)?

The tree is represented by an adjacency matrix, and we have an array for the weights of the vertices.

BFS output:

```
// 0: distances from start vertex
// 1: BFS-order
// 2: parent-IDs
```

I tried this code, it doesn't work on all test cases and it says most of the time that the weight is too small.

Can someone help me find the errors?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Lab5
{

    /**
     *  Problem: Find a maximum weight independent set using dynamic programming.
     */
    
    private static int[] problem(Tree t, int[] weights)
    {
        // Implement me!
        
        //base cases
        if (t.noOfVertices==0) {
            return new int[] {};
        }
        if (t.noOfVertices==1) {
            return new int[] {weights[0]};
        }
        
        //we will implement this using bfs, we will use 0 as the root
        int[][] bfs = t.bfs(0);
        
        //finding leaves
        int leaf[] = new int [t.noOfVertices];
        
        //now we can implement our algorithm
        //M is the maximum weight of the tree if it contains i, and M1 is the maximum weight of the tree if it doesn't contain i
        int M[]=new int[t.noOfVertices];
        int M1[]=new int[t.noOfVertices];
        
        //treating elements that aren't leaves
        int nodeDiscovered[] = new int[t.noOfVertices];
        
        
        for (int i = 0; i<t.noOfVertices; i++) {
            if (t.edges[i].length==1) {
                leaf[i]=1;
                M[i]=weights[i];
                nodeDiscovered[i]=1;
                M1[i]=0;
            }
            else {
                leaf[i]=0;  
                nodeDiscovered[i]=0;
                }
        }
    
        for (int i = 1; i<t.noOfVertices; i++) {
            if (leaf[i]==1) {
                int node = bfs[2][i];
                if (nodeDiscovered[node]!=0) {
                    continue;
                }
                while (node>-1) {
                    int parent = bfs[2][node];
                    ArrayList<Integer> sibs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    if (parent!=-1) {
                        for (int j = 0; j<t.edges[parent].length; j++) {
                            if (t.edges[parent][j]!=bfs[2][parent]) {
                                sibs.add(t.edges[parent][j]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        sibs.add(node);
                    }
                    for (int sib : sibs) {
                        if (nodeDiscovered[sib]!=0) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        M[sib]=weights[sib];
                        for (int k : t.edges[sib]) {
                            if(bfs[0][sib]==bfs[0][k]-1) {
                                M[sib]=M[sib]+M1[k];
                                M1[sib]+=(M[k]>M1[k])?M[k]:M1[k];
                            }
                        }
                        nodeDiscovered[sib]=1;
                    }
                    
                    node = bfs[2][node];
                }
                
            }
        }
        //putting the answers in an arraylist
        ArrayList<Integer> set = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        if (M[0]>M1[0]) {
            set.add(0);
        }
        for (int i = 1; i<t.noOfVertices; i++) {
            if (!set.contains(bfs[2][i]) && M[i]>=M1[i] ) {
                set.add(i);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(set);
        //putting the elements of the arraylist into an array of int
        int[] set1 = new int[set.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i<set.size(); i++) {
            set1[i]=set.get(i);
        }
        return set1;
        
    }

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Do not change any of the code below!
    // Do not change any of the code below!

    /**
     *  Determines if a given set of vertices is an independent set for the given tree.
     */
    private static boolean isIndSet(Tree t, int[] set)
    {
        if (set == null) return false;

        boolean[] covered = new boolean[t.noOfVertices];

        for (int i = 0; i < set.length; i++)
        {
            int vId = set[i];
            int[] neighs = t.edges[vId];

            if (covered[vId]) return false;
            covered[vId] = true;

            for (int j = 0; j < neighs.length; j++)
            {
                int nId = neighs[j];
                covered[nId] = true;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    private static final int LabNo = 5;
    private static final String course = "CS 427";
    private static final String quarter = "Fall 2021";
    private static final Random rng = new Random(190817);

    private static boolean testProblem(int[][] testCase)
    {
        int[] parents = testCase[0];
        int[] weights = testCase[1];

        Tree t = Tree.fromParents(parents);

        int[] solution = maxIsWeight(t, weights);
        int isWeight = solution[0];
        int isSize = solution[1];

        int[] answer = problem(t, weights.clone());

        if (!isIndSet(t, answer))
        {
            System.out.println("Not an independent set.");
            return false;
        }

        int ansWeight = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < answer.length; i++)
        {
            ansWeight += weights[answer[i]];
        }

        if (ansWeight < isWeight)
        {
            System.out.println("Weight too small.");
            return false;
        }

        if (answer.length < isSize)
        {
            System.out.println("Set too small.");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private static int[] maxIsWeight(Tree t, int[] weigh)
    {
        int n = t.noOfVertices;

        int[][] dfs = t.dfs(0);
        int[] post = dfs[2];

        int[] w = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            w[i] = weigh[i] * n + 1;
        }

        boolean[] isCandidate = new boolean[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            int vId = post[i];
            if (w[vId] <= 0) continue;

            isCandidate[vId] = true;

            int[] neighs = t.edges[vId];
            for (int j = 0; j < neighs.length; j++)
            {
                int uId = neighs[j];
                w[uId] = Math.max(w[uId] - w[vId], 0);
            }
        }

        int isWeight = 0;
        int isSize = 0;

        for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            int vId = post[i];
            if (!isCandidate[vId]) continue;

            isWeight += weigh[vId];
            isSize++;

            int[] neighs = t.edges[vId];
            for (int j = 0; j < neighs.length; j++)
            {
                int uId = neighs[j];
                isCandidate[uId] = false;
            }
        }

        return new int[] { isWeight, isSize };
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println(course + " -- " + quarter + " -- Lab " + LabNo);

        int noOfTests = 300;
        boolean passedAll = true;

        System.out.println("-- -- -- -- --");
        System.out.println(noOfTests + " random test cases.");

        for (int i = 1; i <= noOfTests; i++)
        {
            boolean passed = false;
            boolean exce = false;

            try
            {
                int[][] testCase = createProblem(i);
                passed = testProblem(testCase);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                passed = false;
                exce = true;
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (!passed)
            {
                System.out.println("Test " + i + " failed!" + (exce ? " (Exception)" : ""));
                passedAll = false;
               //break;
            }
        }

        if (passedAll)
        {
            System.out.println("All test passed.");
        }

    }

    private static int[][] createProblem(int testNo)
    {
        int size = rng.nextInt(Math.min(testNo, 5000)) + 5;

        // -- Generate tree. ---

        int[] parents = new int[size];
        parents[0] = -1;

        for (int i = 1; i < parents.length; i++)
        {
            parents[i] = rng.nextInt(i);
        }

        // -- Generate weights. ---

        int[] weights = new int[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < weights.length; i++)
        {
            weights[i] = rng.nextInt(256);
        }

        return new int[][] { parents, weights };
    }

}
```

I attached an image that contains the algorithm that I used.

[image]

Comment: The question seems to be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69792201/dynamic-programming-algorithm-that-finds-a-maximum-weight-independent-set-for-a) one